# kotlin reture object throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: servlets, web, kotlin

I want to use kotlin's object as dto

```
@ResponseBody
fun getBindCar(coachId: Long): List<Any> {
    val coach = coachRepository.findById(coachId).get()
    var result = mutableListOf<Any>()
    coach?.cars.forEach { it ->
        var o = object : Serializable {
            var id: Long = 0L
            var licenceNum = ""
        }
        o.id = it.id
        o.licenceNum = it.licenceNum
        result.add(o)
    }
    return result
}
```

when it return ,throw exception

> 2018:04:106:18:35:36.936 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.appsugar.archetypes.web.controller.oa.CoachController$getBindCar$1$o$1 cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourceRegion
>   2018:04:106:18:35:36.950 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Answer (score 0):

When I update the return type from `List<Any>` to `Any` , it works